# ODBC - how to set up ODBC driver for 2 languages (for different code page)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, odbc

How to set up an ODBC driver to operate the Polish code page (1250) and Lithuania (1257) at the same time? Although the code page Lithuanian is wider than the Polish code page, the driver incorrectly passes data to the database.

Database: MS SQL 2005 Standard
OS: Windows

Comment: ODBC talking to which RDBMS?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2005